# Backbone.js template issues with Firefox and IE (works in Chrome)

Tags: css, backbone.js, cross-browser

When this page begins loading [**www.newedenfaces.com**](http://www.newedenfaces.com) everything looks good. But as soon as two big thumbnails in the center are finished rendering, the footer is being pushed down. Well not the footer itself, but the footer's contents, the footer background still remains where it should.

If this issue was consistent across all browsers I'd have easier time tracking down the problem, but since that's not the case I just don't know where to start.

My first instinct was the use of`this.$el.append` instead of `this.$el.html`. *Nope*. Ok, it must be the "sticky footer" then where I use the trick similar to [Bootstrap's Sticky Footer](http://todc.github.io/todc-bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html). *Nope*. I am out of ideas.

**Screenshot of the problem (does not happen in Chrome)**: Footer content is pushed down when page is fully loaded.
[image]

Comment: Probably it has soemthing to do with these two lines for the ".footer" class:
margin-top: -240px;
position: relative;

Comment: @DerWaldschrat you were correct, removing it fixed the problem, which is good enough for now, but the idea was to use it in order to create a sticky footer (footer is always on the bottom even if your page has no content). Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: I'd use absolute positioning to make sure the content is always inside the footer.